# Power BI Data set refresh fails on PowerBI.com

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I had a report published on the Power BI Service and was running fine but the Power BI Dataset started failing with the below error:

> {"error":{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error","pbi.error":{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error_Details_Label","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Refresh is not supported for datasets with a calculated table or calculated column that depends on a table which references Analysis Services using DirectQuery."}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

Strangely the AAS model is not a DirectQuery when I checked in the Visual Studio(attached image below).

[image]

The refresh works fine on Power BI Desktop.
Wondering if anyone can give some guidance on the error and how to fix this.

TIA